# Incorrect output with algorithm2e when using "newtxtext" package

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e, output, bugs, newtx

I have a LaTeX document displaying an algorithm and the output is incorrect when I use the package `newtxtext` with `algorithm2e`. Here is the minimum working example that shows this problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}        
\usepackage{newtxmath}      
\usepackage[boxed]{algorithm2e} 

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm} \LinesNumbered \SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{output}  \Input{the input}  \Output{the output} Do
something  \caption{The  algorithm} \end{algorithm} 
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:
[image]

Problem: In the above picture, the `:` symbol appears on a separated line.

How can I fix this problem?
I could obviously remove the package `\usepackage{newtxtext}`. However, it is a suggested package for Springer books (SVMULT class). Thus, I would prefer to find another solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This <del>feels like</del> *is* a bug <del>to me</del>. Here is a quick fix:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage[boxed]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\LinesNumbered
\SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
\ResetInOut{output}% <- added here
\Input{the input}
\Output{the output}
Do something
\caption{The  algorithm}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image: colon position fixed]

---

The problem is caused by a fixed distance of the colon from the left margin. `\SetKwInOut` is supposed to set this distance according to the longest keyword, but this mechanism somehow failed <del>(I guess `newtxtext` bold font is really wide)</del>. So I used `\ResetInOut` to reset the position of the colon. These can be found in Section 11.1 of the [`algorithm2e` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf).

<del>I conjecture that the distance measurement is done with regular font.</del> I am very confident to say this is indeed a bug.

The length used in creating these `<keyword> : <contents>` is `\inoutsize`, which is the width of `\algocf@inoutbox` and is updated if `\algocf@inoutbox` gets wider. However, I found *two different definitions* for setting up this box, and they are also different from that of `\algocf@inputbox`!!!

```
% In `\SetKwInOut'
\sbox\algocf@inoutbox{\KwSty{#2\algocf@typo:}}%

% In `\ResetInOut'
\sbox\algocf@inoutbox{\hbox{\KwSty{#1\algocf@typo:}\ }}%

% In `\SetKwInput', different box
\sbox\algocf@inputbox{\hbox{\KwSty{#2\algocf@typo:} }}%
```

Clearly, there is a `<space>` missing in the first definition.

Comment: Any progress on solving this possible bug? Today it is still there. Your solution works locally. Thanks a lot.